# MVC3 Postback throwing 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value' HTML error

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, save, ckeditor

I have an MVC3 C# .Net web app.  We are using CKEditor.  We are saving our CKEditor HTML to fields in our DB.  We are escaping the HTML when inserting.  i.e.

```
<strong> Effort estimated for the subtask elements</strong>
```

becomes

```
&lt;strong&gt; Effort estimated for the subtask elements &lt;/strong&gt;
```

This is working fine.  However, when Re-Posting the View on a Drop Down onchange event after loading the View,  I am getting the following error.

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (TextBoeSbTkDescription="<p>
<strong>Exampl...").
```

The values in the text boxes are converted from escaped HTML to unescaped when loading the page.  I put a break point in my Controller Action, but it doesn't get executed prior to the above error being shoen in IE.  Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...I found the answer but I don't know *why* it works.  I have some javaScript in the View that runs on the onchange event of the Drop Down list.

```
function DDWkProdsOnChange(thisObj, selectedIndex) 
{
    document.getElementById('WkProdSeldTxt').value=thisObj.options[selectedIndex].text; 
    document.getElementById('pgSender').value='WkProdDD'; 
    thisObj.form.submit();
}
```

I changed the form submit to use jQuery:

```
function DDWkProdsOnChange(thisObj, selectedIndex) 
{
    document.getElementById('WkProdSeldTxt').value=thisObj.options[selectedIndex].text; 
    document.getElementById('pgSender').value='WkProdDD'; 
   $('form').submit();
}
```

This fixed the issue.  I'd love to know *why*.  I'll see if I can't find an answer